# LWC: Adding top-level data fields to a nested template from a Salesforce Map

Tags: lightning-web-components

My nested string-list template table in LWC is working well, but as a js/LWC noob, I'm struggling with making some enhancements, particularly adding new data points to .

I need to add some information to the top level of data - I currently have a row displaying the map key, but I need to add a couple of links to that row. These links are contained in every row of the list in the map, but I can't figure out how to get that data outside of the iteration template for that map.

Here is the js, with my most recent failure commented out

```js
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getRecords from '@salesforce/apex/CoachPortalHelperClassesEYD.getDeliverables';
export default class CPAssignmentList extends LightningElement {
    
    @api TimeFrame;
    displaydata = false;
    isreview = false;
    
    deliverables=[];
    acceptLinks=[];
    declineLinks=[];

   @wire(getRecords, { TimeFrame: "$TimeFrame" }) 
    getResults(result) {
        
        if(this.TimeFrame == 'Open'){
            this.isreview = true;
        }
        
        if (result.data) {
            const deliverableMap = result.data;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(deliverableMap));
            for (const key in deliverableMap) {
                this.deliverables.push({value: deliverableMap[key], key}); //Here we are creating the top level array to show on UI.
                //this.deliverables.acceptLink = deliverableMap[key][0].acceptLink;
                //this.deliverables.declineLink = deliverableMap[key][0].declineLink;
                
            }
            this.displaydata = true;
        } else {
            console.log('Error');
        }
    }
    
}
```

Here is the relevant subsection of the HTML - I'm not sure you need the rest of it since it all displays fine - I just can't figure out how to get the accept and decline links to appear.

```html
<template for:each={deliverables} for:item="sow">
    <tr class="sowHeaderRow" key ={sow.key}>
        <template lwc:if={isreview}>
            <td data-label="SOW Name" colspan="2">
                <strong>{sow.key}</strong>
            </td>
        </template>  
        <template lwc:else>
            <td data-label="SOW Name" colspan="4">
                <strong>{sow.key}</strong>
            </td>
        </template> 
        
        <td>
            <template lwc:if={isreview}>
                <a href='{sow.acceptLink}' >Accept</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href='{sow.declineLink}' >Decline</a>
            </template>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <template for:each={sow.value} for:item="sowli">
```

Here is the Apex Controller:

```java
global without sharing class CoachPortalHelperClassesEYD {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
    global static map<string,list<Deliverable>> getDeliverables(string TimeFrame){
        map<string,list<Deliverable>> Deliverables = new map<string,list<Deliverable>>();
        list<Statement_of_Work__c> SOWS = getRecords(TimeFrame);
        
        //Get SOW fulfillments and Engagement Reports to display status
        set<string> SOWLI_Ids = new set<string>();
        for(Statement_of_Work__c SOW: SOWs){
            for(sow_line_item__c SOWLI: SOW.sow_line_items__r){
                SOWLI_Ids.add(SOWLI.Id);
            }
        }
        Map<ID, sow_line_item__c> sowli_fulfillment_map = new Map<ID, sow_line_item__c>([SELECT Id, 
                                                                                         (select createddate from sow_line_item_fulfillments__r order by createddate desc limit 1),
                                                                                         (select lastmodifieddate from Coach_Engagement_Reports__r order by lastmodifieddate desc limit 1)
                                                                                         from sow_line_item__c
                                                                                         where id in :SOWLI_Ids]);
        
        
        String currentFiscalYear = [SELECT FiscalYearSettings.Name FROM Period WHERE Type = 'Year' AND StartDate <= TODAY AND EndDate >= TODAY].FiscalYearSettings.Name;

        List<String> args = new String[]{'0','number','###,###,##0'};
        
        for(Statement_of_Work__c SOW: SOWS){
            for(sow_line_item__c SOWLI: SOW.sow_line_items__r){
                deliverable d = new deliverable();
                d.name = SOWLI.Title__c != null ? SOWLI.Title__c : SOWLI.Coach_Deliverables__r.Name;
                sow_line_item__c related = sowli_fulfillment_map.get(sowli.id);
                if(SOWLI.Number_of_Work_Units_Remaining__c == 0){
                    d.Status =  'Fulfilled';
                    if(related.sow_line_item_fulfillments__r.size()>0){
                        d.Status += ' '+ related.sow_line_item_fulfillments__r[0].createddate.Format('MM/dd/yyyy');
                    }
                } else if (related.coach_engagement_reports__r.size()>0){
                    d.Status = 'Resume report saved on '+ related.coach_engagement_reports__r[0].createddate.Format('MM/dd/yyyy');
                } else {
                    d.Status = 'Click to fulfill';}
                d.isOpen = SOWLI.Number_of_Work_Units_Remaining__c == 0 ? False : True;
                d.ExpectedDate = SOWLI.Estimated_Completion_Date__c;
                d.noDate = d.expectedDate == null ? true : false;
                d.SOWLIId = SOWLI.id;
                d.FulfillmentLink = 'coach-fulfillment?SOWLI='+SOWLI.id;
                d.changeDateLink = 'update-estimated-completion-date?SOWLI='+SOWLI.id;
                d.Description = SOWLI.description__c; 
                d.showECDate = SOWLI.Fulfillment_Type__c == 'Engagement Report' && d.isOpen ? True: False;
                d.payRate = '$'+ String.format(SOWLI.Pay_Rate_Unit__c.format(),args);
                string MapKey = SOW.College__c != null ? SOW.College__c : 'Training, Institutes & Retreats';
                if(TimeFrame == 'Open'){
                    MapKey = SOW.Name + ' ' + MapKey;
                    d.acceptLink = 'review-assignment?SOW='+SOW.id+'&accept=Accepted';
                    d.declineLink = 'review-assignment?SOW='+SOW.id+'&accept=Rejected';
                    d.isReview = true;
                } else {
                    MapKey += ' - ' + SOWLI.Year__c;
                    d.isReview = false;
                }
                if(deliverables.containskey(MapKey)){
                    deliverables.get(MapKey).add(d);
                } else {
                    list<deliverable> Dlist = new list<deliverable>();
                    Dlist.add(d);
                    deliverables.put(MapKey,Dlist);
                }
                
            }
        }
        return Deliverables;
    }
    global static list<Statement_of_Work__c> getRecords(string TimeFrame){
        String currentFiscalYear = [SELECT FiscalYearSettings.Name FROM Period WHERE Type = 'Year' AND StartDate <= TODAY AND EndDate >= TODAY].FiscalYearSettings.Name;
        String SOWLIConditions = '';
        User u = [SELECT Id, ContactId FROM User WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getUserId()];
        //string CoachContactId = '0035500001P8zBGAAZ'; 
        string CoachContactId = u.contactId;
        system.debug(CoachContactId);
        if(TimeFrame == 'Current'){
            SOWLIConditions = ' Year__c = \'' + currentFiscalYear + '\' or Number_of_Work_Units_Remaining__c > 0 ';
        } else if (TimeFrame == 'Open'){
            SOWLIConditions = ' statement_of_work__r.status__c = \'Pending Execution\' '; 
        } else {
            SOWLIConditions = ' Year__c < \'' + currentFiscalYear + '\'';
        }
        string SOWQuery = 'Select Id, Name, College__c, (Select Id, Name, Type__c, Estimated_Completion_Date__c, description__c, Number_of_Work_Units_Remaining__c, Pay_Rate_Unit__c, title__c, coach_deliverables__r.name, Year__c, Fulfillment_Type__c From SOW_Line_Items__r where '+ SOWLIConditions + ') from Statement_of_Work__c ';
        SOWQuery += 'where Contractor_Contact__c = \'' + CoachContactId + '\' and ';
        SOWQuery += 'id in (select statement_of_work__c from SOW_Line_Item__c where '+ SOWLIConditions + ')';
        SOWQuery += ' and display_on_portal__c = TRUE and status__c = ';
        if(TimeFrame != 'Open'){
            SOWQuery += '\'Accepted\' ';
        } else {
            SOWQuery += '\'Pending Execution\' ';
        }
        SOWQuery +='order by Institution__r.name asc';
        list<Statement_of_Work__c> SOWS =  Database.query(SOWQuery);
        
        system.debug(SOWQuery);
        system.debug(SOWs);
        return SOWS;
    }
    global class Deliverable{
        @AuraEnabled
        public string name;
        @AuraEnabled
        public string status;
        @AuraEnabled
        public date expectedDate;
        @AuraEnabled
        public string SOWLIId;
        @AuraEnabled
        public string fulfillmentLink;
        @AuraEnabled
        public string changeDateLink;
        @AuraEnabled
        public string description; 
        @AuraEnabled
        public boolean isOpen;
        @AuraEnabled
        public boolean noDate; 
        @AuraEnabled
        public string payRate; 
        @AuraEnabled
        public string acceptLink; 
        @AuraEnabled
        public string declineLink; 
        @AuraEnabled
        public boolean isReview;
        @AuraEnabled
        public boolean showECDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please edit the question adding the Apex controller? Did you update both `Deliverable` class and `getDeliverables` method to include those link?

Comment: I did. I will add the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template `sow` is the object with just two properties: `key` (a string) and `value` (a list of Deliverable). So the items in `sow.value` are the ones with `acceptLink` and `declineLink` properties. Therefore the links should be shown in the for:each on `sow.value`:

```html
<template for:each={deliverables} for:item="sow">
    <tr class="sowHeaderRow" key ={sow.key}>
        <template lwc:if={isreview}>
            <td data-label="SOW Name" colspan="2">
                <strong>{sow.key}</strong>
            </td>
        </template>  
        <template lwc:else>
            <td data-label="SOW Name" colspan="4">
                <strong>{sow.key}</strong>
            </td>
        </template> 
        
        <td lwc:if={isreview}>
            Links <!-- this is just an header -->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <template for:each={sow.value} for:item="sowli">
        <tr class="sowliHeaderRow" key={sowli.SOWLIId}>   
            <!-- current columns: status, description, etc... -->
            <template lwc:if={isreview}>
                <a href={sowli.acceptLink}>Accept</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href={sowli.declineLink}>Decline</a>
            </template> 
        </tr>
    </template>
</template>
```

Moreover as sfdcfox said, merge fields on templates must not be quoted.

Please take a look at these examples of [Relative URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Web_mechanics/What_is_a_URL#examples_of_relative_urls), if `review-assignment` is an app page you may want to change those URLs to:

```java
d.acceptLink = '/lightning/n/review-assignment?SOW='+SOW.id+'&accept=Accepted';
d.declineLink = '/lightning/n/review-assignment?SOW='+SOW.id+'&accept=Rejected';
```

---

Edit: if you want the link at top level, just add two properties to the main object in JS, the one with `key` and `value`:

```js
this.isreview = this.TimeFrame === 'Open'; // An if block is not needed here

if (result.data) {
    const deliverableMap = result.data;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(deliverableMap));
    const deliverables = [];
    for (const key in deliverableMap) {
        const sowLineItem = deliverableMap[key][0];
        //Here we are creating the top level array to show on UI.
        deliverables.push({
            value: deliverableMap[key],
            key,
            acceptLink: sowLineItem.acceptLink,
            declineLink: sowLineItem.declineLink;
        });
    }
    this.deliverables = deliverables; // this way the rerender is triggered only once
    this.displaydata = true;
} else if (result.error) {
    console.log('Error', result.error);
}
```

Then in the HTML you could have:

```html
<template for:each={deliverables} for:item="sow">
    <tr class="sowHeaderRow" key={sow.key}>
        <template lwc:if={isreview}>
            <td data-label="SOW Name" colspan="2">
                <strong>{sow.key}</strong>
            </td>
        </template>  
        <template lwc:else>
            <td data-label="SOW Name" colspan="4">
                <strong>{sow.key}</strong>
            </td>
        </template> 
        
        <td lwc:if={isreview}>
            <a href={sow.acceptLink}>Accept</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href={sow.declineLink}>Decline</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <template for:each={sow.value} for:item="sowli">
        <tr class="sowliHeaderRow" key={sowli.SOWLIId}>   
            <!-- current columns: status, description, etc... -->
        </tr>
    </template>
</template>
```

Please note that you never need an if-else or a ternary operator to set a Boolean, you could just use the expression you're evaluating.
That's why you can change

```java
d.isOpen = SOWLI.Number_of_Work_Units_Remaining__c == 0 ? False : True;
d.noDate = d.expectedDate == null ? true : false;
```

To:

```java
d.isOpen = SOWLI.Number_of_Work_Units_Remaining__c != 0;
d.noDate = d.expectedDate == null;
```

Moreover there is no need to evaluate `TimeFrame == 'Open'` in each iteration since it doesn't depend on the current iteration item. You could evaluate it just once before the outer for, i.e. defining `Boolean isReview = TimeFrame == 'Open';`, then use that value as condition for the if block and set `d.isReview = isReview;` outside the if-else block.

Comment: but I don't want the links at the detail level. I want them at the top level. Surely there's a way to do this.

Comment: @ScottWilliams I edited the answer to show the link at the top level.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was looking for. I had figured out last night that I could have added a flag to the first sowli in any given deliverable and another iteration template of the sowlis in the <td> where the accept/decline links are so it would just display the result of one sub-record, but this is much cleaner. I appreciate you knowledge and time.

Comment: @ScottWilliams You're welcome, glad I could help.